# Also at the beginning of a sentence

Tags: conjunctions, word-order

> **Also**, I like animals very much and I would like to help them when they suffer.
>
> I **also** like animals very much and I would like to help them when they suffer.

Is **also** at the beginning of the sentence correct? Does it sound too formal to you?

Comment: Both sentences are fine. People worry about "formal" English far too much. Never use a long word where a short one will do, and you will be alright.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences are fine to use. There has been a rule passed down through generations, incorrectly telling people that they **must not** use words such as **but**, **or**, **and** or **however** at the beginning of a sentence.

Using conjunctions at the beginning of sentences is [not forbidden](http://grammarist.com/grammar/conjunctions-to-start-sentences/). And, you can choose to do this to emphasise a point. However, you need to be careful not to do it too much.